# How would you represent a list of searchable users in the directives template file?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

**AngularJS Question:** If a directive sets an array of multiple objects on the scope called users with properties, name and age. How would you represent a list of searchable users in the directives template file?

**AngularJS Question:** With the AngularJS service downloadable here and its JSON response here create an AngularJS controller that would use the named service, draw out the inventory from the JSON response from the service and interate that back to the scope for a template to digest.

An example of a working controller without a template file is fine.

http://clsmoocprod.blob.core.windows.net/uploads/hiring/moduleassets/b819f500-8638-e411-80bb-00155d536807/fb5937c4-8c38-e411-80bb-00155d536807/angular-question-level2-service-example.js

```
 APP.factory('inventory', ['$http', function ($http) {

functiongetInventory(){
return $http.get('/inventory/get').then(function(result){
returnresult.data;
        });
    }
```

return {
getInventory: getInventory
    };

}]);
http://clsmoocprod.blob.core.windows.net/uploads/hiring/moduleassets/b819f500-8638-e411-80bb-00155d536807/dec77f23-8e38-e411-80bb-00155d5369ef/angular-question-level2-json-example.js

```
 [
    { 
        stockId: 654654,
        name: "Printer Ink",
        available: 23
    },
    { 
        stockId: 564645,
        name: "Paper Reems",
        available: 120
    },
    { 
        stockId: 094835,
        name: "Mother Boards",
        available: 12
    },
    { 
        stockId: 798787,
        name: "Stationary Packs",
        available: 160
    },
    { 
        stockId: 987562,
        name: "Computer Mice",
        available: 56
    },
    { 
        stockId: 879432,
        name: "Computer Keyboards",
        available: 50
    }
]
```

Comment: check edited quetion

Comment: @DivineDesign, I still don't understand the issue or the objective. Specify what you want to achieve and what you have tried